# Show properties of the prototype object?

Tags: javascript

Here I have a simple inherit function that takes an object argument and returns a newly created object with the passed object as it's prototype object.

```
function inherit(p) {
if (p == null) throw TypeError(); //p must not be null
if(Object.create) { //if the object.create method is defined
    return Object.create(p); //use it
}

//type checking
var typeIs = typeof p; //variable that holds type of the object passed
if(typeIs !== 'object' && typeIs !== 'function') {
    throw TypeError();
}

function f() {}; //dummy constructor
f.prototype = p; //prototype
return new f(); //return new constructor
}

var $f0 = {}; 
$f0.x = 1; 
var $g0 = inherit($f0); 
$g0.y = 2;
var $h0 = inherit($g0); 

console.log('x' in $h0); //true
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames($h0.prototype)); //throws error
```

The issue I am having is after I run my `inherit` function, I am not able to look up the objects prototype properties.

How would I go about showing a prototype objects properties?

Comment: `$h0.__proto__`, `.prototype` is a property of constructor functions not objects

Comment: That worked.  Is this the only way to accomplish this?  I was under the impression that `__proto__` wasn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(`[`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)`($h0))` or the non-standard [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). `prototype` is the name of the property on the constructor only.